# while using def function i got this error

Tags: if-statement

```
def even_or_odd(num):
    if num%2==0:  
        return "the number {} is Even".fromat(num)
    else:
        return "the number {} is Odd".format(num)
```

> ---
>
> AttributeError
> Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 even_or_odd(20)
>
> in even_or_odd(num)
> 1 def even_or_odd(num):
> 2    if num%2==0:
> ----> 3        return "the number {} is Even".fromat(num)
> 4    else:
> 5        return "the number {} is Odd".format(num)
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fromat'

Answer (score 1):

You should change the line to

```
 return "the number {} is Even".format(num)
```

The error is just a typo.